# Access Azure Private Endpoint from on-premise

Tags: azure, networking, dns, azure-virtual-network, azure-dns

### Context

I have a [hub-spoke network architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke?tabs=cli) in Azure and the hub vnet has a site-to-site VPN connection with on-premise.

I have a storage account that I want to access privately. So, I created a private endpoint in the spoke vnet and I connected the hub vnet with the `privatelink.blob.core.windows.net` private DNS zone.

To resolve the storage account private link from on-prem, I added an Azure Firewall in the hub vnet acting as a DNS proxy and all traffic for `privatelink.core.windows.net` is sent to this firewall.

This setup is summarized [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#on-premises-workloads-using-a-dns-forwarder).

### Problem

When I do a `nslookup [xxx].blob.core.windows.net`, the first time I get the storage account private IP. BUT, subsequently, I get the storage account public IP.

### Question

How is this possible ?

### My guess

#### First attempt

- Client sends request for `[xxx].blob.core.windows.net` to the on-prem DNS server
- The on-prem DNS server forwards the request to the hub firewall
- The hub firewall forwards the request to Azure DNS
- Azure DNS responds that `[xxx].blob.core.windows.net` is a CNAME for `[xxx].privatelink.blob.core.windows.net` which in turn is a CNAME for `blob.[yyy].store.core.windows.net` and resolves to the private IP

#### Subsequent attempts

- Client sends request for `[xxx].blob.core.windows.net` to the on-prem DNS server
- The on-prem DNS server sees in its cache that `[xxx].blob.core.windows.net` is a CNAME for `blob.[yyy].store.core.windows.net` and tries to resolve that name
- The on-prem DNS server resolves the public IP

Comment: On the On-prem dns server, have you tried forwarding DNS requests for blob.windows.net instead of privatelink.blob.windows.net ?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a private endpoint for the storage account, it doesn't mean the storage account can't be accessible from the Internet. It only means you can access the storage account from both VNet and Internet. You can understand it from the screenshot below:

[image]

So if you only want the storage account to be accessible only from the hub VNet, you need to change the **Allow access from** into **Selected networks**, and the selected network in the hub VNet.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In my case, the access is only allowed from selected networks and no virtual network is selected below because I don't want to talk to the storage account via its public endpoint. However, I have two private endpoint connections: one for blob and one for dfs.

Comment: @flappy OK, then you need to add the network rule to set the default action with Deny, and only allow the traffic from the selected VNet. Steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-cli#managing-default-network-access-rules). Then you can only access the storage account from the VNet, not the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and found someone may have solved it by adding DNS configuration to Azure VPN Client (on Windows).
[resolving private dns zone over point-to-site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/39571/not-resolving-private-dns-zone-over-point-to-site.html)
I have not tried this solution myself but found a workaround by adding mapping entry to `host` file in `C:Windows/system32/driver/etc` system folder.